# Picture in the email send by script

Tags: php, image, email, batch-file

Good morning. 
This is my first post so please forgive me for any mistakes.
I am using PHPMailer for sending emails and it works perfect. However...
I created php script which does a select query on SQL Server DB and sends email to users with reminder. If I run this script directly from browser, emails with embedded picture are sent without problems, but if I run this php file using .bat file emails are sent without a picture - just red cross in place where the picture should be.
To attach a picture I am using:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("images/logo.jpg","logo","logo.jpg")
```

and in the email body:

```
<img src="cid:logo">
```

Any ideas why a picture is not attached when php is ran from the bat file?
thanks
LukaszKU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify a full path to image, like: `/usr/home/user/.../images/logo.png`

Comment: WOW, it is working. I don't know why it was working once I ran php in browser but not from batch file.

Comment: When run in browser, your web server sets an environment variable, specifying a path to your document root, so you can use relative paths. When run from batch, there is no such path.